# Matrix of a Linear Transformation with respect to new Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T: \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be defined by $T(x,y,z) = (y+z,z,0)$. If $V$ belongs to $\mathbb R^3$ such that $T^2(V)$ is not zero, then show that $B = {V, T(V), T^2(V)}$ forms a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. Also, compute the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$.

My idea - Let $V = (x,y,z)$, then we get $B = {(x,y,z),(y+z,z,0),(z,0,0)}$. What to do next ?
If the basis is in numbers such as $B' = {(1,2,1),(0,5,3),(0,0,7)}$, I can calculate the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $B'$ but how do I find it for $B$.

Comment: Could you use MathJax to write your question? It is much more likely to get positive answers this way. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The way you find the matrix representing $T$ to a basis $B=\{u,v,w\,\}$, is by calculating the coefficients $a,b,\dots$ in $T(u)=au+bv+cw$, $T(v)=du+ev+fw$, $T(w)=gu+hv+iw$ and sticking them in a matrix. You can do that easily for $B=\{V,T(V),T^2(V)\,\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linearity of $T$ is clear. Take $v := (x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $T^2v \neq 0$. In other words $z\neq 0$.

Suppose for some $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb R$ we have
$$ \alpha v + \beta Tv + \gamma T^2v =0 $$
Conclude that $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 0$, which means $\{v, Tv, T^2v\}$ is linearly independent and so must be a basis in $\mathbb R^3$.

The transition matrix from canonical basis to the new basis looks like
$$ C := \left (
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & y+z & z \\
y & z & 0 \\
z & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right ) $$
where the column vectors are the coordinates of $v, Tv$ and $T^2v$ respectively (with respect to canonical basis).

Let $T_1$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to canonical basis and $T_2$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to new basis. It is well known that
$$ T_2 = C^{-1} T_1 C. $$
The columns of $T_1$ are the coordinates of the images $Te_1,Te_2,Te_3$ with respect to the canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$.

Comment: Isn't this the hard way?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it is. But you already answered the easy variant in the comments.

Comment: The point of the question was to see how to do it the easy way.